# talking to a remote redis server using redis-py (python wrapper over redis)

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-ec2, redis

I have installed redis on an independent database server(ec2 instance). And it has been installed and configured properly. 
Now all that I want to do is from my webserver, I connect to it, and make changes to its key value store.

I have a python/django application running on heroku, and I am using PostgreSQL for everything else, I am using redis just to store some temporary variable in the KV sets.

Now, I install https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py on my localserver, and webserver.

To test the connection and check if things are working well, I try the following in my environment :

```
>>> pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='MY_DBSERVER_IP_ADDRESS', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=pool)
>>> r.set('foo', 'bar')
```

this gives me an error - `ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting 54.235.xxx.xxx:6379. Connection refused.`

How do I connect? What am I missing?

Comment: try to see if you can access the remote server via telnet: just do "telnet MY_DBSERVER_IP PORT" in the terminal

Comment: `ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 6379`
PING 6379 (0.0.24.235) 56(124) bytes of data.
^C
--- 6379 ping statistics ---
32 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 31081ms

Comment: So there's your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the config is set to only bind to 127.0.0.1
You just need to find your config (/etc/redis/redis.conf on Ubuntu) and comment out the bind 127.0.0.1 line.

Answer (score 3):

So what I ended up doing was, removing uncommenting `bind 127.0.0.1` to `bind 0.0.0.0`